# Class not found when using flink sql to write delta table

Tags: scala, apache-flink, delta

Guys
When I am trying to write the delta table in flink sql, it wrote few data successfully and then it throw an exception when it continues writing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.jdk.CollectionConverters$.mapAsJavaMapConverter(Lscala/collection/Map;)Lscala/collection/convert/Decorators$AsJava;
```

My env:
FLink version:1.16.0
hadoop:3.3.1
delta:3.0.0
scala:2.13

fix my issue and reslove this bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink not supporting Scala 2.13. You should use 2.12 (only supports Scala 2.12.7) Look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-265+Deprecate+and+remove+Scala+API+support)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
However, when I use the scala-libraries-2.12.7, the flink throw a not found exception :
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$
This class is only for scala-2.13.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is a common error when there is incompatibilities between the libraries/versions. Check that all dependencies using scala-2.12. And try some basic stuff before conversions.